# How to check for a part of the string in the file?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a code that will check all files under given directory and sub directories for a string passed from the web page.  As of now I have this code:

```
    private void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory, string origDirectory, string ObjectName)
    {
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);

        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            ProcessFile(fileName, origDirectory, ObjectName);
        }

        foreach (string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
           ProcessDirectory(subdirectory, origDirectory, ObjectName);
    }

    private void ProcessFile(string path, string origDirectory, string ObjectName)
    {
        if (ObjectName != "")
        {
            var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            List<string> fileItems = new List<string>(fileLines);

            if (fileItems.Contains(ObjectName))
            {
                string sExt = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLower();

                if (sExt == ".txt")
                {
                    listTextFiles.Items.Add(path.Replace(origDirectory, ""));
                }
            } 
          }
```

It works, but the problem is that it looks only for a complete word in the file.  For example, if I look for the word 'Account', and the file contains word 'Account', my code will work.  If the file contains the word 'AccountCode', my search won't find it.  Is there a way to fix it?

Another question, how to add a counter that would show at the end of the process how many files were checked under the given directory and all sub directories.

Answer (score 3):

This is an awfully round-about way of doing it. Just load the entire file content and use `IndexOf`:

```
var content = File.ReadAllText(path);

if (content.IndexOf(ObjectName) > -1) {
    // rest of your code here
}
```

There is no need to load line-by-line, initialize a whole new list with those lines, and check each line.

This also gives the benefit of a partial search, as you've asked.

You could probably improve this immensely by carefully auditing how much memory you're consuming. Both your method and the one I provided here will likely allocate large blocks of memory, only for them to be useless after the conditional check. Consider using a `StringBuilder` and re-using it with each file.

Comment: For "very large" files it might make sense to perform the operation on a stream (perhaps even an IEnumerable of lines) .. but this is indeed a very simple (and likely sufficient) method.

Comment: @user2864740 Indeed. A Stream or a StringBuilder being re-used would be much more efficient in terms of memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

`if fileItems.Contains(ObjectName))` will search the list `fileItems` on the condition: *if that list contains items that is equal to* `ObjectName`.

You probably want: *if that list contains items that **contains** `ObjectName`*. So change to this:

```
if (fileItems.Any(e => e.Contains(ObjectName)))
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question. Because you use recursion here you would need to declare a property or class level variable and increment it in your ProcessFile method e.g.:

```
public int NumberOfMatches { get; set; }

ProcessFile...
{
 if (fileItems.Contains(ObjectName))
 {
      NumberOfMatches++;
 }
```

As a side note there is no reason to use recursion here you could simply get all the files with a single call:

```
string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

You may also consider mutli-threading if performance is an issue:

```
   Parallel.ForEach(allFiles,
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
        allFiles =>
        {
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When checking contents of a string, don't forget to implement a comparer for the string

```
If(string.Contains( value ,StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ))

// Apply logic...
```

It's very often left out...